How to set a background image using object-fit and have it fill the parent container without setting a height for the parent?
<div class="parent">
     <img class="background" src="image.jpg">
     <div class="content">
         <h1>Some Text</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tincidunt magna quis nibh congue hendrerit. Maecenas ultricies diam eget diam volutpat, a posuere leo varius. Pellentesque varius nulla nec felis dapibus, vel varius turpis dignissim. Suspendisse porttitor cursus orci vitae rutrum.</p>
     </div>
</div>


.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.background {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-position: center;
    object-position: center;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 3rem;
}

I need to be able to have a flexible height on the parent div that is dependent on the content within it, with the image filling the entire space behind the content; using a background image is not an option, nor is setting an exact height.

.parent won't grow to the height of .content, when the latter is absolute positioned. Why is that necessary to begin with? You said something in the comment to the already given answer, that parts of this are influenced by CSS you have no control over - can you clarify, which ones those are, please?
